# SharpGL WPF draw from code behind not using OpenGLDraw

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpgl

I'm trying to draw on a `OpenGLControl` from the code behind (or preferably using the MVVM pattern) without using the `OpenGLDraw eventhandler`. The reason for this is that I'm using it for augmented reality and the camera is using an external trigger, so I want to draw whenever a new frame comes in from the camera. In the example I've used a timer to simulate the camera.

I've tried the following:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Example1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="400" Width="600"
        xmlns:sharpGL="clr-namespace:SharpGL.WPF;assembly=SharpGL.WPF">
    <Grid>
        <sharpGL:OpenGLControl
            x:Name="glControl"          
            OpenGLInitialized="OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized"
            RenderContextType="DIBSection"
            DrawFPS="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using SharpGL;
using SharpGL.SceneGraph;
using System.Timers;

namespace Example1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Timer clock = new Timer(1000f / 60f);
        float rotatePyramid = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized(object sender, OpenGLEventArgs args)
        {
            OpenGL gl = args.OpenGL;
            gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

            clock.Elapsed += OnFrame;
            clock.Start();
        }

        private void OnFrame(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            OpenGL gl = glControl.OpenGL;

            //  Clear the color and depth buffers.
            gl.Clear(OpenGL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | OpenGL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            //  Reset the modelview matrix.
            gl.LoadIdentity();

            //  Move the geometry into a fairly central position.
            gl.Translate(0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

            //  Draw a pyramid. First, rotate the modelview matrix.
            gl.Rotate(rotatePyramid, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

            //  Start drawing triangles.
            gl.Begin(OpenGL.GL_TRIANGLES);

            gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

            gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

            gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

            gl.Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
            gl.Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

            gl.End();
            gl.Flush();

            rotatePyramid += 3.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

This only renders a black screen with the FPS counter in it. I think it has to do with not getting the right OpenGL object. I would really like to use the MVVM pattern and using bindings, but if that's not possible then code behind would also work, as long is I can draw whenever I get a frame from the camera.